# How to run Linux libraries on Docker on Windows?

Tags: windows, docker, tensorflow, caffe

I am working on Windows and I need to use libraries, which are availible only with Linux (TensorFlow,Caffe). I would like to run the software on Docker. I cannot understand the docker mechanism clearly, so I am completly lost, when its up to my problem. What should I do and how should it work?

Comment: In Windows 10 Anniversary edition you can use the Linux subsystem instead of a VM.

Comment: Which OS *do* you want to use? Docker is only useful for packaging and deploying your application, it won't make Linux code run on Windows without a VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

**About Windows Docker hosting capabilities (container on a Windows host):**

- Windows 10 offers Docker host capabilities, but only based on Hyper-V, i.e. by means of Linux-like VMs.
- [Windows 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_server) offers native Docker host capabilities (thanks to @friism to point this out below).

**About Windows Docker container capabilities (Windows in a Container)**:

- [Windocks](https://www.windocks.com/community-docker-windows) offers .Net and SQL Server support within Containers (thanks for @paul).
- On Windows 2016, a windowsservercore base Docker image allows you to run Windows services, see this [simple example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_server).
- On a Windows 10 & Hyper-V, the nanoserver base  Docker image allows you to run Windows commands (see here a [helloworld PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_10) example). Requires the Windows version of the Docker daemon and will not work on Linux Docker hosts, see [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/unknown-blob-when-pulling-microsoft-nanoserver/20291).

---

**Original Answer:**

Bad news first: Docker is not *(not fully correct, see edit above)* supported on Windows hosts natively (okay, that depends on how you define "natively". I mean, Docker always needs a Linux-like Docker host, see the good news below).

The good news is that Docker can be used on Windows by running Docker containers on a Docker host, which is running as a virtual Linux machine on Windows e.g. on VirtualBox, VMware or, nowadays officially preferred on Windows 10 Professional: on Hyper-V.

The best news for you is: since Docker containers are running on Linux-like hosts and are offering a Linux environment within a container, you can install any Linux software within the container the same way as you would do on a native Linux machine. Say, you start a Docker container with interactive terminal from an Ubuntu Docker image, by issuing the command

```
docker run -it ubuntu bash
```

you can run any `apt-get` command in this container.

Note, that the data you have changed in a container are not meant to be persistent. Once you have installed the SW in the container, you may want to preserve your work by building a new Docker image from the new container using [docker commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) commands. An advanced and automated way to create such images is to add your tested installation commands as RUN directives in a Dockerfile and to build the image from it without the need to manually run an interactive container and manually add the software.

Comment: Windows 10 also has a Linux subsystem (aka Bash on Windows) so you *don't* need a Linux VM. Scott Hanselman has a demo that [shows using TensofFlow on Windows this way](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlayingWithTensorFlowOnWindows.aspx)

Comment: Interesting. Do you know whether Docker runs on this subsystem? I understand Vladislav's question so, that he wants to run his software on Docker and I thought up to now that Docker requires a virtual machine, if you want to run it on Windows.

Comment: I have found this [serverfault link](http://serverfault.com/questions/767994/can-you-run-docker-natively-on-the-new-windows-10-ubuntu-bash-userspace) and this [docker forum link](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-for-windows-and-windows-subsystem-for-linux/12854/12) that is discussing the docker on Windows bash topic. If the answers are (still) right, Docker is most probably not supported on Windows 10 bash. Do you agree?

Comment: No. Docker isn't a user-mode application, it requires specific Linux Kernel features. `Docker for Windows` though installs and configures a Linux VM automatically during installation. Commands, files etc work the same. The point is though that one *doesn't* need Docker to use TensorFlow, but if Docker is installed on Windows, it would work inside the Linux host without changes

Comment: Understood. I thought, Vladislav's goal was to use the libraries on Docker, but I might have misunderstood his primary goal and he just wants to use the libraries on Windows.

Comment: You don't use a library on Docker, you use it on the host OS, in a "partition" created by Docker. If you manually install the dev version of Docker (1.13) instead of 1.12 you can use Windows containers today. The OP should decide *which* OS he wants to use first, then decide on packaging his code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122863/discussion-between-olli-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: Note that the Docker Engine has been ported to Windows and runs natively on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/containers_welcome?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Native Windows container support based on Docker's open source is coming from Microsoft on Windows Server 2016, and is also available from WinDocks on Windows 8,Windows 10, Server 2012 and Server 2016.  A free Community Edition download is available here:  https://www.windocks.com/community-docker-windows

Comment: @paulstanton Windocks doesn't offer containers, simply because the OS doesn't have the relevant features. It offers a form of isolation for very specific products. I suspect they do what Bitnami does for years. They may use the same APIs as Docker but that doesn't mean they offer containers at all.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 Anniversary edition includes a Linux subsystem (Ubuntu-based), what is commonly called `Bash on Windows`. It's not just Bash, it's a translation layer that allows you to run user-mode applications on Windows itself, *and* the Ubuntu binaries on top. You can use it to run user-mode applications.

Scott Hanselman shows how you can use TensorFlow this way using exactly the same command you would on a Linux machine in [Playing With Tensor Flow On Windows](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlayingWithTensorFlowOnWindows.aspx). Copying from Scott's post:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev
$ sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

will install TensorFlow and

```
$ cd tensorflow/models/image/mnist
$ python convolutional.py
```

will start executing the MNIST demo

The only annoyance is that it's Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, not the latest 16.04

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote? You *can* use Tensorflow on Windows 10, and you *can* package the very same code to run inside a Docker container that targets Linux.