# Can I use Windows 10 Insider preview to build a docker image

Tags: windows, docker

I have a Eclipse App that only installs on Windows, while I have a Mac. I have downloaded the Windows 10 ISO from the [insider preview program](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO). Can I use it in docker to build a docker image? What can be the base image? The alternative is to use the VirtualBox, and install windows 10 in it. But I don't want to go for it, because I want to share the image with other colleagues who are on Windows.

Comment: Note that Windows Docker containers can only be based on Nano Server or Windows Server Core. While you can run server-based containers on Windows 10, the containers themselves cannot be based on Windows 10. Docker running on Windows also doesn't support GUI apps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a Windows Container on a Mac you will need to intall Windows 10 **Anniversay Update** ISO as a VM via Virtualbox or install the operating sysem using **Bootcamp**.

Windows 10 Anniversay Edition now has native support for Containers so you can run docker images for **Windows Server 2016** and/or **Nanoserver.**

Your colleagues will also need Windows 10 Anniversary Edition to run the image on their machines.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Windows virtual machine to run Windows 10 on your MAC. See also [the answer in this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39370258/how-to-run-linux-libraries-on-docker-on-windows/39373756#39373756) for a discussion of docker container types and docker hosts types.

**Background:**

Linux-based docker containers only run on Linux docker hosts while Windows-based docker containers only run either [on Windows 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_server) or on Windows Nanoserver, where a Nanoserver can run [on Windows 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_server) or on [Windows 10 Professional + Hyper-V](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_10).

If you want to run either Linux-based or Windows-based docker containers on a MAC, you will need a Linux-based or a Windows-based virtual machine, respectively.

**Is it possible to exchanging Docker images instead of virtual machine images to reduce the size?**

Not in your case, I think.

If you think about reducing the image size you intend to share with your colleagues, you might think about running Windows containers on a Windows virtual machine on your MACs and exchange the smaller docker images instead of sharing virtual machine images. However, this would require [nested virtualization](http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/nested-virtualization-hyper-v-windows-server-2016/) of Hyper-V and this is supported on Hyper-V-capable hardware only (see also an Hyper-V on Hyper-V example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/user_guide/nesting)). Since you are using a MAC, I fear, you need to share the larger virtual machine image or better find a way to share only parts of it (e.g. share project code via git instead).